# Call JS function inside PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a `foreach` loop that generates an `input` with type of `checkbox` with `items` (from DB).
Right now, there is no default checkbox that is checked and every time a user checks the checkbox it calls to JS function.

Now, the clients wants me to check the first checkbox by default. I know how to check it but how do I call the JS function by default?

This is my HTML - the `update_addon()` is JS func.

```
<? foreach ($pros as $pro):?>
    <label class="checkbox text-left">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" 
         onchange="update_addon(<?=$pro['id']?>,this)">
         <?=$pro['name']?> ( <?=$pro['price']?> )
    </label>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

The `update_addon()` is an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax problem. You must put question mark on this part "`<?=$pro['id']>`".

```
 <? foreach ($pros as $pro):?>
     <label class="checkbox text-left">
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" 
          onchange="update_addon(<?=$pro['id']?>,this)">
          <?=$pro['name']?> ( <?=$pro['price']?> )
      </label>
  <? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: while the code may solve the problem, update this answer with required details like where is the problem, what is the problem, etc.

Comment: It is just copy-past. The code works fine, now I need to change it a bit to fit the new situation

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it.
did a click() event on js file to click the first checkbox.
thanx